# Removing SafeCracker & Inserted Assets

Tags: safecracker, jquery

I'm trying to remove ALL inserted assets in SafeCracker, I've got my opening tag like so:

```
{exp:safecracker 
    channel="{prv_channel}"
    return="{segment_1}/{segment_2}/{segment_3}" 
    entry_id="{entry_id}"
    class="form-inline"
    include_jquery="no"
    include_assets="no"
    datepicker="no"
}
```

So in theory, should this remove all the "inserted" code? Well... It doesn't :(

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"> 
if (typeof EE == "undefined" || ! EE) { 
var EE = {"BASE":"http:\/\/website\/index.php?","THEME_URL":"http:\/\/website\/themes\/cp_themes\/default\/","PATH_CP_GBL_IMG":"http:\/\/website\/themes\/cp_global_images\/","filebrowser":{"endpoint_url":"ACT=2","window_title":"File Manager","theme_url":"http:\/\/website\/themes\/cp_themes\/default\/"},"fileuploader":{"window_title":"File Upload","delete_url":"C=content_files&M=delete_files"},"lang":{"or":"or","resize_image":"Resize Image","return_to_publish":"Return to Publish","confirm_exit":"When you leave, any data entered will be lost. Are you sure you want to leave?","add_new_html_button":"Add New HTML button"},"publish":{"show_write_mode":true,"title_focus":true,"smileys":false},"user_id":1,"XID":"ac7721bdd8cfa9b80a37ce5b27f741bae5d7ec41"};}
mySettings = {"nameSpace":"html","onShiftEnter":{"keepDefault":false,"replaceWith":"<br \/>\n"},"onCtrlEnter":{"keepDefault":false,"openWith":"\n<p>","closeWith":"<\/p>\n"},"markupSet":[{"name":"b","key":"B","openWith":"<strong>","closeWith":"<\/strong>","className":"btn_b"},{"name":"i","key":"I","openWith":"<em>","closeWith":"<\/em>","className":"btn_i"},{"name":"blockquote","key":"Q","openWith":"<blockquote>","closeWith":"<\/blockquote>","className":"btn_blockquote"},{"name":"a","key":"A","openWith":"<a href=\"[![Link:!:http:\/\/]!]\"(!( title=\"[![Title]!]\")!)>","closeWith":"<\/a>","className":"btn_a"},{"name":"img","key":"","replaceWith":"","className":"btn_img"}]};
myWritemodeSettings = {"nameSpace":"html","onShiftEnter":{"keepDefault":false,"replaceWith":"<br \/>\n"},"onCtrlEnter":{"keepDefault":false,"openWith":"\n<p>","closeWith":"<\/p>\n"},"markupSet":[{"name":"b","key":"B","openWith":"<strong>","closeWith":"<\/strong>","className":"btn_b"},{"name":"i","key":"I","openWith":"<em>","closeWith":"<\/em>","className":"btn_i"},{"name":"blockquote","key":"Q","openWith":"<blockquote>","closeWith":"<\/blockquote>","className":"btn_blockquote"},{"name":"a","key":"A","openWith":"<a href=\"[![Link:!:http:\/\/]!]\"(!( title=\"[![Title]!]\")!)>","closeWith":"<\/a>","className":"btn_a"},{"name":"img","key":"","replaceWith":"","className":"btn_img"}],"onTab":{"keepDefault":false,"replaceWith":"\t"}};
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="http://website/index.php?ACT=58&amp;ui=core,widget,mouse,position,draggable,resizable,button,dialog&amp;plugin=scrollable,scrollable.navigator,markitup,thickbox,toolbox.expose,overlay,tmpl&amp;v=1366647338"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
// <![CDATA[
$(document).ready(function() {
    if (typeof SafeCracker == "undefined" || ! SafeCracker) { var SafeCracker = {markItUpFields:{}};}});
// ]]>
</script>
```

WHY!?

I can't remove them in the module file due to me needing them elsewhere on another template.

How can I remove these? Because jQuery isn't included before these scripts, it's just throwing big fat errors in console! Eugh.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're likely looking at the new docs that just went up, for EE 2.7 (released yesterday).

Under EE 2.6.1, the parameter you want is called `safecracker_head`, not `include_assets`.

Comment: Perfect! I didn't notice that. Doh. I'll need to upgrade to 2.7 now as well.